# Add LED Indictor lights to 3 or 4 way battery selector switch

Tags: led, switches

Situation: Two battery banks in a solar setup (12VDC).  A main DC set of circuits (lights, pump etc) can be powered by either of the banks through a three way selector switch (Bar1, Bat2 or Off - high amp rating).  The battery banks share a common ground. I do not have access to the system for a couple of weeks so cannot experiment.
Problem:  I would like to add in LED indicator lights (for example I have a number of 12Vdc LEDs (with built in resistors)) to show which of the two battery banks is selected.  This would be easy if this only involved DPDT toggle switches or if the two ground circuits where isolated.  I have not been able to find any examples and am not sure if it is possible.  To further complicate the problem, there is another similar circuit with a 4-way switch (including a "both" option).  Thanks for any help[image: Simple diagram]

Comment: Add one LED, white, and shine it onto the switch so that it can always be clearly seen? :)

Comment: Add a cheap voltage and ammeter to them? Probably need a large shunt. Does the voltage drop on the selected one vs the unselected one? Then a comparator could be used.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines - it would require insertion of some other components to measure the voltage difference, the battery series current, etc. Or you could inject a frequency onto the DC lines and filter that frequency on the other side. I can't think of a simple solution.